# What do I do if Javascript is disabled by a client?

Tags: javascript

My site heavily depends upon Javascript and if I turn it off my website looks real ugly.

I want to force the user to use Javascript by show him a notification to turn it on, else prompt him that site can't be viewed.

What do I do to achieve this?

Comment: Seconding ereOn: If you can't make your site working without JS, simply tell the user, that it's necessary because of (insert understandable reason here). Don't force her to anything.

Comment: I am curious why this question has been pushed down to -3. Surely people are not dropping this question because of some moral ethics code?

Comment: Hi guyumu, that's what i am thinking why ereOn and some other  commentators downvoted my question! May be they are against using javascript or may be they can't digest the success that JQuery has been getting these days. I wish i could also downvote him 10 times more than what i am downvoted :)

Comment: @guyumu: Actually, I didn't downvote. But forcing users to enable Javascript is a bad practice. What if someone forces you to use Windows 95 because he is too lazy to make a compatible software ? The same logic applies here.

Comment: @Nitesh Panchal: please check my total downvote count, you'll be surprised :) I love Javascript, and jQuery is a good thing. It's forcing users and forgetting about visually impaired people that I dislike.

Comment: Well don't use the software. As simple as that! There was no reason to downvote and i know you were the 1st one who actually started downvoting

Comment: @Nitesh Panchal: I have a total downvote count of 0. But if you know that for sure, SO must be buggy. Or you're mistaking... what is more likely ?

Comment: @Nitesh - don't sweat it, I gave you the exact answer to your question, and I got downvoted too

Comment: Ok! i saw ereOn's profile just now. It's 0 :p. I had a doubt on you only since you are the only one here who has been singing aloud not to javascript. I asked a question, you should have answered my question pertaining to the question. Instead you didn't even post your answer and the persons who are answering it, with them also you are arguing by commenting on their answer.

Comment: @jaywon: Whether the answer is correct is up to the community to decide. And why the hell does everyone think that I'm a serial downvoter ?!

Comment: @Nitesh Panchal: I won't "argue" anymore. I made my point. Whether you want to consider it or prefer to just ignore people that try to teach you good practices is up to you. Good luck.

Comment: @ereOn - that's the second time you've slammed me for something i didn't say. I said I got downvoted, not that YOU did it. My point to him was not to take the comments/voting so seriously, and my advice to you would be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>
   Your browser does not support JavaScript!
</noscript>
```

Also, feel free to google 'html script tag' and see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Answer (score 6):

Have a look here:

[noscript tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)

All you can do is test that javascript is turned on or not, and show a notification that the site is best viewed with javascript turned on.

Comment: ...and ask the user nicely to re-enable Javascript. No other option.

Comment: @SF, haha was editing my post as you added that to say pretty much the same thing

Comment: I'm pretty sure visually impaired users will be pleased to learn that "this website was not designed for blind people ! Just go away !"

Comment: @ereOn - from the post it pretty much sounds like that's exactly how it was designed. I never said building a heavily JS dependent site was a good idea, I just answered the question.

Comment: My apologies. I misread the "best viewed" part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

First off, be warned that forcing the user to do anything is usually considered quite rude.  Lots of people keep javascript either disabled entirely or severely restricted precisely because some twerp wanted to use it to force them to do something or look at something.

With that said, you can include some text in `<noscript></noscript>` tags.  That text will only show if the browser doesn't have javascript, or has it disabled.

Answer (score 2):

For your question:
By default show the notification, and with JS + some sort of document/DOM Ready event just remove the notification. Try not to do this on window/onload because then you'll see the notification until ALL resources of that page have been loaded, which takes longer than dom ready. That way, everybody who doesn't have JS will see the message.

But ideally you'd just want to have a website that works with, or without javascript. Maybe unobtrusive javascript is a nice search term for you.

Comment: Hi CharlesLeaf, i am using JQuery and its plugins and it won't work if user disables javascript. What do i do?

Comment: Nitesh, my answer and the <noscript> solution are the only 2 things you can do. So read about both of them, and just try them out.

Comment: Also, remember that not everybody has Javascript disabled by choice - people at the office usually don't have an option, and in some cases firewalls/virus scanners like to block things.

Comment: @CharlesLeaf - you are right, my apologies. I still don't think it's a particulary "good" answer, but it would work i suppose. That's what the noscript tag is essentially for without all the extra work

Comment: @CharlesLeaf, not to mention screen readers for visually impaired users.

Comment: I think ereOn is strong supporter of not to use javascript :p. But i am using world's most popular javascript library, JQuery and my sit will work only if javascript is enabled due to lightbox and other plugins. I wish i could rate him negative if he had answered :). Unnecessarily my question has been downvoted.

Comment: @jaywon @ereOn I know, but you could also combine both techniques. What I ment was more that with unobtrusive javascript you usually load a separate "js only" stylesheet that hides/shows things that you don't need if JavaScript is working. I guess in this case <noscript> IS better yes. 

@Nitesh well, you have plenty of options so I'm sure you'll figure something out. And when you have time read http://www.alistapart.com/articles/behavioralseparation

Answer (score 2):

I watched an [interesting talk](http://ejohn.org/blog/building-a-javascript-library/) by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/about/) (The creator of JQuery) and he even mentions in his video, do not rely on Javascript.

Comment: +1. That's a sane advice indeed. A good website must remain usable without Javascript. That doesn't prevent Javascript to improve usability, but one **must not** rely on it.

Comment: A good website does what it's client/clients expect from it. What ever moral issues you have with it does not apply. There are sites that I work on that would be impossible to use without javascript. But, our environment has these base builds that fits that requirement and always will. So if someone does not have javascript enabled, his boss will be comming to see him. It's a nice to have, even a good practice, but only where it's possible and worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You create a landing page that uses a `<noscript>` tag to inform the user that your web site doesn't work without Javascript. Then you go and pray $DEITY for forgiveness because you added to the general mire pool that is the web.