# Alternatively load page via php if ajax fails

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to replace the contents of a div with an external file via ajax. the code I am using to do so is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML="<img src='loadingImage.gif'>";

    var x = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var x = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    } else {
        // fallback
    }

    x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php", true);
    x.send("");
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(x.readyState == 4) {
            if(x.status==200) 
                document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = x.responseText;
            else 
                document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = "Error loading document";
        }
    }
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="aside">This is other content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Questions:**

If JavaScript is enabled, then the above code works fine but if JavaScript is disabled, then php should load that file. How d I do this?

Comment: Why use AJAX at all if you can do it with your serverside language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fallback to entirely different index page if user has javascript disable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936002/how-to-fallback-to-entirely-different-index-page-if-user-has-javascript-disable).  It's not ideal, but the first answer is probably your best bet.

Comment: see this tutorial also: http://hungred.com/how-to/determine-whether-javascript-is-enabled-disabled-via-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to make your code backward compatible without JavaScript then you really have no reason to use `AJAX` at all. If you just want the string into your `aside` Element then do something like:

```
//first the PHP page 'other_content_1.php'
<?php
  $resp = 'Whatever String Response You Want';
?>
//now your other page
<?php
  include 'other_content_1.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'
'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='aside'><?php echo $resp; ?></div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='should_be_external.js'></script>
<body>
</html>
```

Note, that if you want this to happen besides `onload` then you would submit a form using `$_POST` or `$_GET` to handle the PHP response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying the noscript option?
See: [What do I do if Javascript is disabled by a client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911704/what-do-i-do-if-javascript-is-disabled-by-client)

However, if you have a lot of pages this might be a lot of work if you use jquery/ajax throughout your pages - which I am guessing you do or loading them in with jquery/ajax would be slightly pointless.

Answer (score 0):

By the time the web page is displayed in the browser and found that JS is not supported, PHP/server already served the page. You can try this.

- #aside element can have text & link informing user about not having JS support and take another page
- PHP can load the file and serve the content in the new page.

If JS is supported, your above code will be anyway replacing the above link.